# How to remove blank lines without using tr?

Tags: linux, awk, sh, esxi

`vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms` prints like this:

```
id  virtual machine name
11  VirtualMachine1
15  Virtual Machine 1
6   Virtu al Machin e 1


9   Virtual Machine one
21  VirtualMa chineone
```

I get the ids using the following:

`vm_ids=$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' | egrep "[0-9]+")`

And next I want to loop through them and execute a command against each one so I do this:

```
i=2
for id in $vm_ids
do
   vm_name=$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk -v i=$i -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" 'NR==i {print $2}' | egrep "$[[:alnum:]]")
   echo "Doing something to ID: $id for machine: $vm_name"
   $((i++))
done
```

My script is returning a `null` value when it gets to those empty lines.

I made the virtual machine names like this just to demonstrate the variety of ways that a name can be returned.  Since ESXi doesn't have `tr` installed, how can I remove those lines from my output, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes there's a much better way of doing this. See the answers and comments you got yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in vim, execute this command:

```
:v/./d
```

**EDIT**

with grep: `grep -o '^[0-9]\+'` should work without worrying about empty lines. It gives all the leading numbers (ids).

with your command:

```
vm_ids=$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms|grep -o '^[0-9]\+')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this does and how I do it exactly?

Comment: Typing the command the way you have it does not work for me.  If I type `vim-cmd` I get the following as options `hbrsvc/ internalsvc/ solo/ vmsvc/ hostsvc/ proxysvc/ vimsvc help`

Comment: can you briefly explain, why did you tag the question with 'vim'? and what is the `vim-cmd` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was `vim-cmd` that I tagged.  `vim-cmd` is a set of built-in ESXi utilities.

Comment: @inquisitor it's ok. I added a grep option, should work for your requirement. give it a test please.

Answer (score 4):

With `grep`:

```
grep . file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NF' file
```

---

However you can replace your command with a single call to `awk`:

```
vm_ids=$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk '/^[0-9]+/{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/^$/d' inputfile
```

Since you're already piping the output to awk, a better approach would be to replace your command with:

```
vm_ids=$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk 'NF && NR>1 {print $1}' | egrep "[0-9]+")
```